# CSS opacity div, links not working inside that div

Tags: css, opacity

I have a footer with an opacity of 0.4 as you can see here...

```
.footer{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 1101px;
    background-color:#888888;
    min-height:145px;
    opacity:0.44;
    filter:alpha(opacity=44);
}
```

and I have another div class inside the footer called footerNav...

```
.footerNav{
    padding-top:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width:1080px;
}

.footerNav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.footerNav li {
    float: left;
}

.footerNav ul a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 30px 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:36px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

and with a list inside the div class

```
<div class="footerNav">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--footerNav-->
</div><!--footer-->
```

My problem is the links are not clickable and the color of the links is suppose to white, how do I fix this?

Comment: What browser are you running this in? If you look at this tinker: https://tinker.io/2494e it works. I added the hotpink background, cause its sexy. ;)

Comment: Very sexy, lol I am running firefox 11

Comment: Okay, I'm running FF11 as well and the code you posted works ootb, fyi. z-index as proposed further down is the way to go if you want to bump it up the element stack but I think there might be some other css or something blocking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an z-index to your footerNav

```
.footerNav{     
    padding-top:10px;     
    margin: 0 auto;     
    position: relative;     
    width:1080px; 
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: This got my links working, but the white font still doesnt show

Comment: since you are using opacity white color might have some problem try some dark color